# Skipped XML tag input binding in OpenUI5 XMLModel

Tags: xml, binding, sapui5

Sample XML:

```
<data>
  <items>
    <item><text1>text 1.1</text1><text2>text 1.2</text2></item>
    <item><text2>text 2.2</text2></item>
  </items>
</data>
```

There is no text1 tag in second item.
This XML is loaded to XMLModel which is bound to Table with sap.m.Inputs in cells.

It is not possible to edit cell corresponding to skipped XML tag: after input losing focus text just disappears. This is not so if using JSONModel: new items are created. Is it possible to do similar for XMLModel too?

Test is available here: http://embed.plnkr.co/wa0oBXbq6Exfj3NqNKmQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, **I believe it is a bug of XMLModel**.

See the `setProperty` method of [XMLModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/model/xml/XMLModel-dbg.js).

```
XMLModel.prototype.setProperty = function(sPath, oValue, oContext, bAsyncUpdate) {
    var sObjectPath = sPath.substring(0, sPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
        sProperty = sPath.substr(sPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    // check if path / context is valid
    if (!this.resolve(sPath, oContext)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!this.oData.documentElement) {
        jQuery.sap.log.warning("Trying to set property " + sPath + ", but no document exists.");
        return false;
    }
    var oObject;
    if (sProperty.indexOf("@") == 0) {
        oObject = this._getObject(sObjectPath, oContext);
        if (oObject[0]) {
            oObject[0].setAttribute(sProperty.substr(1), oValue);
            this.checkUpdate(false, bAsyncUpdate);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        oObject = this._getObject(sPath, oContext); //oObject would be empty  
        if (oObject[0]) {
            jQuery(oObject[0]).text(oValue);
            this.checkUpdate(false, bAsyncUpdate);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

};
```

In the last else statement, oObject would be empty with sPath "text1". so **the new value is not set.**

> oObject = this._getObject(sPath, oContext);

While if you see the `setProperty` method of [JSONModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel-dbg.js).

```
JSONModel.prototype.setProperty = function(sPath, oValue, oContext, bAsyncUpdate) {
    var sResolvedPath = this.resolve(sPath, oContext),
        iLastSlash, sObjectPath, sProperty;

    // return if path / context is invalid
    if (!sResolvedPath) {
        return false;
    }

    // If data is set on root, call setData instead
    if (sResolvedPath == "/") {
        this.setData(oValue);
        return true;
    }

    iLastSlash = sResolvedPath.lastIndexOf("/");
    // In case there is only one slash at the beginning, sObjectPath must contain this slash
    sObjectPath = sResolvedPath.substring(0, iLastSlash || 1);
    sProperty = sResolvedPath.substr(iLastSlash + 1);

    var oObject = this._getObject(sObjectPath);
    if (oObject) {
        oObject[sProperty] = oValue;
        this.checkUpdate(false, bAsyncUpdate);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Check the below line, sObjectPath would be **'/items/1'**, so the **oObject is returned and the new value is set**.

> var oObject = this._getObject(sObjectPath);

Hope it helps. Thank you.